# How to append list to another list

Tags: python, list

I am currently building a program and want to sort data (called component in the code) by week number.

```
wList = []
thing = []
Wstart = 0

for component in list:

    curDate = component[0]

    year, month, day = (int(x) for x in curDate.split('-'))    
    currentWeek = int(datetime.date(year, month, day).strftime("%V"))

    if Wstart == currentWeek or Wstart == 0:
        wList.append([component, component, component, component])
        Wstart == currentWeek
    else:
        thing.append(Wlist)
        wList = []
        wList.append([component, component, component, component])
        Wstart == currentWeek
```

Basically I want to reset the Wlist when a new week is available, and store the Wlist in a list called thing, but when I run print(thing) I got "[]".

I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: What's `veckaList`?

Comment: Looks like `veckaList` should be `wList`.

Comment: complete your code snippet please, ex. list cannot be a variable name...
example data for component and list would also be very helpful!

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post now. I've searched for extend but I am not sure if it is the right thing

Comment: Can you show the original list and the desired result?

Comment: Is `Wstart == currentWeek` a copying error or in the original code? It should be `=` to assign the variable.

Comment: `for component in list:` - what is `list`? I doubt you want to iterate over the type...

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python list handling", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Overall, I suggest that you work through a tutorial on working with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a variable called "list" that you are not showing in your code? Because the for loop won't even begin if you try to go through the list variable. Also veckaList isn't defined anywhere, so that should also cause an error.

Post a more complete code to get better answers.

as for adding a list to a list

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []

list2.append(list1)

>list2
>[[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Comment: He already corrected the `veckaList` copying error.